# Intermittent network connectivity on Intel I219-V(2) when Hyper-V enabled

Tags: networking, hyper-v, docker-for-windows

As the title states, I'm getting intermittent network connectivity on host (Win 10 Edu) when I have Hyper-V enabled. Hyper-V is required for Docker to run. I've attempted to reinstall NIC drivers, update bios etc. without any success.

Here is my Control Panel > Network & Internet > Netowrk Connections:
https://i.imgur.com/eQu1wI0.gifv

As you can see the vEthernet (Default Switch) keeps resetting, which causes host to loose network connectivity for a few seconds.

Any ideas on what's going on and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this by setting my main Ethernet connection to shared.

[image]